# Prove that if $K$ is a finite extension of F, $K \neq F$ then there exits $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $[K:F]=p^n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a field of characteristic $p\neq 0$ , Let $F=\{a^p | a\in K\}$

Prove that if $K$ is a finite extension of F, $K \neq F$ then there exits $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $[K:F]=p^n$

I'm new to field theory the question tells us that $K\neq F$ but by Fermat we get that $a^p=a$ so thats mean that $K=F$ . What am I missing here? and can you give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: The standard example is $K=\Bbb{F}_p(x) = Frac(\Bbb{F}_p[x])$ giving $F=\Bbb{F}_p(x^p)$. You need to write $K/F$ as a tower of extensions of the form $E(b)/E$ with $b^p\in E$.

Answer (score 1):

Fermat says that $a^p = a$ in the field $\mathbb{F}_p,$ not every field of characteristic $p.$

Comment: You mean not every field of characteristic $p$? because $F$ is a subfield of $K$ so they have the same characteristic $p \neq 0$

Comment: @needhelp Yes, sorry, typo, will fix.